# Page not visible in 'All pages' after being added through PHP

Tags: php, pages, plugin-wpml

I'm adding some pages pragmatically as a subpage. This all works well on a test website in 1 locale. However, on the live website we have WPML with 2 locales. When adding them there, these pages DO NOT show up in the all pages list.

Also accessing their url give a 404. However, when you access the edit mode directly: `https://xxxxxxx.nl/wp-admin/post.php?post=3280&action=edit&lang=nl`
The page 'comes to life' (even without saving) and is visible as sub-page in the 'all pages' page.

Any idea how to get this working properly upon insertion in the db by PHP? Thanks!

```
function add_my_custom_page() {

    for( $i=1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {

        $my_posts = array(
          'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( "Video $i" ),
          'post_name'     => "v-$i",
          'post_type'     => "page",
          'post_content'  => 'test',
          'post_status'   => "publish",
          //'post_excerpt'  => "v-$i",
          'post_parent'   => 3269,

          'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
          'page_template' => "page-full-width.php",
        );

    

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_posts, true );
        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably related to WPML, you need to ask this in a WPML community or reproduce the problem without WPML so it's confirmed the plugin is unrelated. 3rd party plugin user/dev support questions are offtopic here

Comment: just a wild guess here, but maybe set the language before inserting via `do_action('wpml_switch_language', 'es');` where 'es' is the language you want to system to operate in..?